# ProFTPd config via SFTP and FTP

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, sftp, proftpd

I have a ProFTPd that actually use FTP protocol, but I would like to use SFTP too. 
I found a solution with `<VirtualHost>` block, but it doesn't work for me.

```
  <IfModule mod_sftp.c>
      <VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>

        TLSEngine          off
        SFTPEngine         on
        Port               2222
        SFTPLog            /var/log/proftpd/sftp.log
        Include            /etc/proftpd/sql.conf

        SFTPHostKey        /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
        SFTPHostKey        /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

        SFTPCompression    delayed
        DefaultRoot        ~
        RequireValidShell  on

     </VirtualHost>
  </IfModule>
```

This is the output of the `/var/log/proftpd/sftp.log`

```
2021-10-11 11:03:32,289 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]: using '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key' as 256-bit ECDSA hostkey
2021-10-11 11:03:32,289 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]: using '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key' as 256-bit ECDSA hostkey
2021-10-11 11:03:32,291 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]: sent server version 'SSH-2.0-SFTP Server'
2021-10-11 11:03:32,291 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]: received client version 'SSH-2.0-PuTTYFileZilla_3.46.3'
2021-10-11 11:03:32,291 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]: handling connection from SSH2 client 'PuTTYFileZilla_3.46.3'
2021-10-11 11:03:32,363 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]:  + Session key exchange: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
2021-10-11 11:03:32,363 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]:  + Session server hostkey: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
2021-10-11 11:03:32,363 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]:  + Session client-to-server encryption: aes256-ctr
2021-10-11 11:03:32,363 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]:  + Session server-to-client encryption: aes256-ctr
2021-10-11 11:03:32,363 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]:  + Session client-to-server MAC: hmac-sha2-256
2021-10-11 11:03:32,363 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]:  + Session server-to-client MAC: hmac-sha2-256
2021-10-11 11:03:32,363 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]:  + Session client-to-server compression: none
2021-10-11 11:03:32,363 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]:  + Session server-to-client compression: none
2021-10-11 11:03:32,504 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]: sending acceptable userauth methods: keyboard-interactive,password
2021-10-11 11:03:32,626 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]: expecting USER_AUTH_INFO_RESP message, received SSH_MSG_IGNORE (2)
2021-10-11 11:03:32,627 mod_sftp_pam/0.3[20791]: PAM authentication error (7) for user 'sql_user': Authentication failure
2021-10-11 11:03:32,627 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]: sending userauth failure; remaining userauth methods: keyboard-interactive,password
2021-10-11 11:03:32,628 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]: unhandled SSH_MSG_USER_AUTH_INFO_RESP (61) message, disconnecting
2021-10-11 11:03:32,628 mod_sftp/0.9.9[20791]: disconnecting (Unsupported protocol sequence)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. The solution to have your FTP Daemon works on both FTP/21 and SFTP/2222 is to have  <VirtualHost 0.0.0.0> section inside of <IfModule mod_sftp.c>.

I'm sharing this part of my configuration file in /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf which works fine.

> 

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
  
    SFTPEngine on
    Port 2222
    SFTPAuthMethods password
    RequireValidShell      off
    SFTPLog /var/log/proftpd/sftp.log
    Include /etc/proftpd/sql.conf

    SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
    SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
    
    SFTPCompression delayed
    DefaultRoot
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The `SFTPAuthMethods password` was missing from mine!
Thank You so much!! :-)))

Comment: Sorry for the bump, but I am in the process of setting up SFTP access as well, but I think I'm missing something. I set up an FTP user (in Virtualmin/Webmin), enabled the modules, and entered the VirtualHost, but I still get access denied. I thought I was going to be able to omit having to use a key or that my key would be automatically accepted and then just use the FTP password I'd set up earlier. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance @zeerk & Zareh